# Is there a way to add a separate graph for each host on a Datadog dashboard, when the hosts frequently change?

Tags: monitoring, dashboard, datadog

I'm trying to make a dashboard to monitor a process which runs on 5 remote machines simultaneously. I want the dashboard to display the metrics for each machine separately - basically, I want to create five separate graphs, one for each machine that runs the process. My problem is that the remote machines are reassigned periodically, so I have no way of knowing the name of the host at any given time.

I've tried creating five separate graphs, with each one filtered by a different host name tag, but the graphs do not seem to pick up the new host when the lease for the process is changed. I also know you can split out one graph for each host using metrics explorer, but I haven't found any way to automatically do that on a dashboard. Does anyone know if this is possible? Leases for the process are assigned through AWS, if that is helpful.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Datadog just released the 'Split Graph' feature. It's available from the metrics explorer, or by editing any existing graph. You can choose a feature to split the graphs, and they should dynamically be updated based on your timeline. The maximum supported number of graphs is currently 48.

There doesn't seem to be any official documentation or release notes for the feature just yet.

Example:

Splitting a graph from the metrics explorer
[image: Splitting a graph from the metrics explorer]

Split graphs by host
[image: Split graphs by host]